# Are there permissions for deleting attachments to work items in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I want to prevent users from accidentally deleting attachments to work items in TFS2013. I have not been able to find a work item permission that controls the ability to delete attachments. Is there such a permission, or is there an alternative mechanism I should consider? I have looked at making attachments Read-Only when the work item is in the closed state, but the attachments field does not appear in the Field Reference dialog when creating a new rule on the state in the Workflow editor.

Comment: I have a feeling this isn't possible at the moment, sorry.

Comment: Not possible. Not even a standard ISubscriber server side plugin can prevent the deletion. This would need to be implemented as a RequestFilter, which I wouldn't let anyone do that hasn't extensively worked on server side extensions. It's very hard to get this right. Instead you could move the work items to an area and use the area permissions to restrict edit rights.